# How to prevent `TAB` from adding a newline for each new address (To/Cc), in Gnus + BBDB?

Tags: completion, gnus, bbdb

When I'm adding a comma and a new address at To or Cc or Bcc in Gnus, there is a new line added when completing the address. I end up with:

```
My Address <address@example.com>,
Another Address <another@example.com>,
Yet Another <yet@example.com>
```

instead of

```
My Address <address@example.com>, Another Address <another@example.com>, Yet Another <yet@example.com>
```

Each `TAB` I use for completion results in the addition of a newline. And I can't sent the message, all addresses must be one one line.

How can I fix this to not add a newline when using `TAB` for address completion?

I'm using Emacs 25.2.2, Gnus 5.13, BBDB 3.2.

Comment: Not sure why it's happening, but "all addresses must be on one line" is not true: you can have each address on a separate line, as long as each line starts with white space, indicating to the mail system that it is a continuation line. See [Long header lines](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-2.2.3).

Comment: You're right. It works, I'm not sure why I had an error some time ago when having new lines.